# how to add own number range in java

Tags: java, numbers, int, range

I want to create my own range of numbers in Java, and still be able to use the normal ones. I just can’t seem to solve it! That is without hard coding every result.

Let’s say. Integers go like 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8…. and so on (I know! there are also negative int’s)

Now, I’d like to make my own “numbers” that can be used both as integers and their own type.

A simple cut of the numbers range is 1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 7, 6, 9, 10, 11, 8, 13, 14, 15, 12, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 16… and so on… A sheet of the all numbers are shown below. (I don’t need any numbers above 767, but the next number is 512, then 769+ and so one.

```
1
2
3
5
4
7
6
9-11
8
13-15
12
17-23
16
25-31
24
33-47
32
49-63
48
65-95
64
97-127
96
129-191
128
193-255
192
257-383
256
385-511
384
513-767
```

Now lets call these numbers tni’s (opposite of int)

Let’s say I’d like to add (int)A to (tni)B This should be normal math. So if A = 4 and B = 6, the result will be 10, not 8.

But if I want to see which one of 2 tni’s are the highest. Let’s say A=8 and B=10, id will tell me that A is higher, as in the tni range, 8 comes after 10.

Is this possible?

Comment: Don't know about others, but I didn't understand anything.

Comment: No, it's not possible. You have to create your own class and do all math and conversions through methods of this class, you can't overload + operator or casting.

Comment: okay. sad, but thanks, then ill do it the hard way... thx for your time, ill be back in 2 hours and accept this answer if no one else tell's me you are wrong (i no you are not, but i hope... :)  )

Comment: Your question is quite confusing. Why would anyone think that adding 4 and 6 would give 8? Is there a rule behind the sequence of numbers you describe? What do the hyphens mean between some of the numbers - "17-23" for example? Why would these numbers be "TNI"s - what is it that makes them different from integers? I would like to help, but your description of the problem is rather confusing. It sounds like what you want to do is to find the position of a "TNI" within an ordered sequence, which is fairly easy, but I would like to understand the problem first.

Comment: @JavaApprentis sorry but all I understood from this question was that you're some kind of a mad scientist. Does this pattern follow a certain function?

Comment: @Jon I don't know about the 4 + 6 = 8 thing, but the sequence of numbers seems to be completely arbitrary. The hyphens are just used as shorthand for a range of numbers (e.g. 17-23 == 17 18 19 20 21 22 23). The reason they're different is that they come in a different order. The only reason the order matters (as far as I can tell) is for greater/less than comparisons. That's my interpretation, anyway.

Comment: @Tharwen ah, right I see. It's just shorthand. In that case, you could do this with a function that contains a for loop, but there is no "clever" way of doing this.

Comment: @Jon I've had a go at a semi-clever solution. I think this is just a really awkward problem. Incidentally, JavaApprentis, what's the bigger problem you're trying to solve here? There might be a better solution higher up the problem stack.

Comment: downvoting this question in 1,2,8 and so one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way I see of doing this is to create an array denoting each 'normal' int's position in the tni sequence.

For example:

```
int[] tniArray = new int[768];

tniArray[0] = 0;
tniArray[1] = 1;
tniArray[2] = 2;
tniArray[3] = 3;
tniArray[4] = 5; //This is because the number 4 comes at position 5 in the tni sequence
tniArray[5] = 4;
tniArray[6] = 7;
tniArray[7] = 6;
tniArray[8] = 11;
//etc.
```

Then, you can compare them with a method like this:

```
boolean IntGreaterThanTni(int Int, int Tni){
    return (Int > tniArray[Tni]);
}
```

Yes, this is a fairly inelegant solution, but it seems like you have an inelegant problem in the first place.

Comment: This is a good answer - it reminds me of a similar problem from "Programming Pearls", surprised I didn't think of it. This is a much faster solution than my own, but requires an additional "set up" step for the array corresponding to the indexes. You might also have a problem with numbers that are not present at all in the sequence having a "special value", like "-1", and which therefore always get flagged as being "before" any number that *is* in the sequence. It really depends upon  the exact problem definition, which is by no means clear.

Comment: Yea, 
this is what I meant by hard coding. Well, it’ll work. Thanks :)

As to what its for.
It’s a project on a cellular automata (see Conways game of life, or Langton loops for some examples)

In this automata, there are different  types of cells, each with a value defined based on both their surroundings and their own value.

Each cycle of the program, a cell will look to all sides, to find out where it will have the best values.

Now, the best values are as shown in the tni array. 
Mostly the higher the better, but there are some golden numbers,

Comment: that are placed higher than their actual numeric placement.

These golden numbers are 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 12, 16, 24, 32… and so one.

Hope this gives a little light to what it is used fore.

Comment: @JavaApprentis I suppose you could write a parser for the string of numbers you posted in the OP. That wouldn't be too hard but might be more effort than just writing them in yourself.

Comment: @Tharwen.
Hmm. I don’t know, it might be a good idea. 
If the automata is at some point expanded so higher numbers are to be used, it’ll make thinks easy in the long run.
Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite confusing, but here is what I think you mean. You have an ordered sequence of numbers which is not defined by any function. You want to be able to tell if a given number in the sequence comes before or after another within the same sequence.

It doesn't look like you can use anything like binary search for this, so if you want to determine the position of a number within the sequence, the quick and dirty way to do it is to iterate through the sequence from the beginning, and stop when you find your target number. Potentially, this means that you could iterate through the entire sequence twice in order to find the position of two numbers A and B, within the sequence, and then determine if one comes before the other.

The code below does what you want. It's not very OO, but it works.

```
public class FunnySequence {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // First few numbers in the sequence
        int arr[] = new int[]{
                1,
                2,
                3,
                5,
                4,
                7,
                6,
                9,
                10,
                11,
                8
        };

        int a = 8;
        int b = 10;

        System.out.println("Position of A: "+ 
                   findPosition(arr, a));
        System.out.println("Position of B: "+ 
                   findPosition(arr, b));
    }

    public static int findPosition(int[] arr, int num) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (num == arr[i]) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```